# Zend_Form: remove default filter from one element

Tags: php, filter, zend-form

I extended Zend_Form with my own class and let inherit all my forms from that. My base-class applies a default filter to all form elements that strips out double whitespaces, basically:

```
return trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $value));
```

While usually i want this on every element, there are some occasions where it breaks stuff, for example on textareas (newlines get removed aswell) so i'm looking for a way to disable that default filter on certain elements.
I tried this (unsuccessfully):

```
$element->clearFilters();
```

however within the forms init() method that filter is not yet set ($element->getFilters() returns an empty array), only when calling methods like __toString() or isValid() it gets applied, but I'd rather not overwrite those methods just to get rid of the filter. There must be a better way?!

The cleanest solution would probably be to opt-in that filter and not apply by default - but I'd rather keep it default and find a way to exclude certain elements.

Comment: @skooli did you try `$element->removeFilter('filterName');` also make doubly sure it isn't actually a validator. If it is use `$element->removeValidator('validatorName');`

Comment: same result as `clearFilters()` - since the filter isn't set yet in `init()` it has no effect. And it's definitely a filter :p `$this->setElementFilters(array('FixWhitespaces'))`

Comment: @skoolio true to form Zend Documentation isn't up to scratch, however I did find this. `If at any time you need the unfiltered value, use the getUnfilteredValue() method` maybe it could be of some use.

Comment: @martswite yes, I considered that, however when a form is submitted with invalid values zend will pre-fill textareas with the submitted value and also applies the filter there (so all newlines will be removed again). Seems to be more work to get rid of the default filter than just apply the filter explicitly where wanted...

Comment: @skoolio I'm a bit baffled as to why the validator only seems to apply itself at the point of calling isValid() or __toString() this seems like strange behaviour to me. Can you post the code for your validator and show how you implement it?

Comment: form base class: http://pastebin.com/SUvN3Ty5 /
filter: http://pastebin.com/RmkTpYic /
example how filter isnt registered during init(): http://pastebin.com/1cr1Ejru

Comment: PS: same behaviour when calling the `Zend_Debug::dump()` after `$this->addElement($field)`

Comment: @skooli do you need to call the Form constructor from your _Some_Form_ class?

Comment: parent constructor is called automatically if you dont specify your own - otherwise my filter wouldn't be applied (but it is). Another addendum how the filter is suddenly there in `__toString()` http://pastebin.com/AHwaSnfW

Comment: @skooli Well I'm completely baffled as to the reason for this behavior. I'm sorry that I couldn't be more useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

[skooli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/767956/skooli), the OP, already self-answered the question:

Quote:

---

**Resolved!**

The `setElementFilters()` method will run over all elements currently added to the form and apply the filter, so now I've just overwritten that method to work like this:

```
public function setElementFilters(array $filters) {
    foreach ($this->getElements() as $element) {
        if(!($element instanceof Zend_Form_Element_Textarea)) {
            $element->setFilters($filters);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

While this will work with all textareas I cant exclude arbitrary fields of other types. Should I need that I'll probably create a dummy filter that does nothing but can be used to determine whether the `fixWhitespaces` filter should be omitted.

---

<sub>Note: It's absolutely [OK to self-answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions/12519#12519) your own question. Please just post it as an real answer, but *not* in a question or comment. Posting as real answer helps to keep the "Unanswered" list more clear (avoids making other people wasting their time).</sub>